# Using Mockito's generic "any()" method

Tags: java, unit-testing, mocking, mockito

I have an interface with a method that expects an array of `Foo`:

```
public interface IBar {
  void doStuff(Foo[] arr);
}
```

I am mocking this interface using Mockito, and I'd like to assert that `doStuff()` is called, but I don't want to validate what argument are passed - "don't care".

How do I write the following code using `any()`, the generic method, instead of `anyObject()`?

```
IBar bar = mock(IBar.class);
...
verify(bar).doStuff((Foo[]) anyObject());
```

Answer (score 149, accepted):

Since Java 8 you can use the argument-less `any` method and the type argument will get inferred by the compiler:

```
verify(bar).doStuff(any());
```

---

#### Explanation

The new thing in Java 8 is that the [*target type*](https://dev.java/learn/type-inference#target-types) of an expression will be used to infer type parameters of its sub-expressions. Before Java 8 only arguments to methods where used for type parameter inference (most of the time).

In this case the parameter type of `doStuff` will be the target type for `any()`, and the return value type of `any()` will get chosen to match that argument type.

This mechanism was added mainly to be able to compile lambda expressions, but it improves type inferences generally.

---

#### Primitive types

This doesn't work with primitive types, unfortunately:

```
public interface IBar {
    void doPrimitiveStuff(int i);
}

verify(bar).doPrimitiveStuff(any()); // Compiles but throws NullPointerException
verify(bar).doPrimitiveStuff(anyInt()); // This is what you have to do instead
```

The problem is that the compiler will infer `Integer` as the return value type of `any()`. Mockito will not be aware of this (due to type erasure) and return the default value for reference types, which is `null`. The runtime will try to unbox the null return value by calling the `intValue` method on it before passing it to `doStuff`, and the exception gets thrown.

Comment: I am pleasantly surprised every time this answer gets an upvote! I would have guessed that the question would not attract much attention since Java 8, since the `any` method should just work. You don't lookup answer for things that just work!

Comment: I came here because I didn't know why my code did not work with `any()` but was ok with `anyBoolean()`, which the last part of your answer sheds light on beautifully.

Answer (score 300):

This should work

```
import static org.mockito.ArgumentMatchers.any;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.verify;

verify(bar).DoStuff(any(Foo[].class));
```

Comment: just in case someone need it in Scala: `verify(bar).DoStuff(any[Array[Foo]])`

Comment: I had a problem with the import, I was using the any() from hamcrest in my imports and it collided with the one from mockito.

Comment: Please have a look into the API, the class argument is just used for casting, the method still accepts any kind of object! http://site.mockito.org/mockito/docs/current/org/mockito/Matchers.html#any(java.lang.Class). Use isA() for this case http://site.mockito.org/mockito/docs/current/org/mockito/Matchers.html#isA(java.lang.Class).

Comment: This class is now deprecated in order to avoid a name clash with Hamcrest. Use org.mockito.ArgumentMatchers

Answer (score 16):

As I needed to use this feature for my latest project (at one point we updated from 1.10.19), just to keep the users (that are already using the **mockito-core version 2.1.0 or greater**) up to date, the static methods from the above answers should be taken from `ArgumentMatchers` class:

```
import static org.mockito.ArgumentMatchers.isA;
import static org.mockito.ArgumentMatchers.any;
```

Please keep this in mind if you are planning to keep your Mockito artefacts up to date as possibly starting from version 3, this class may no longer exist:

As per 2.1.0 and above, Javadoc of org.mockito.Matchers states:

> Use `org.mockito.ArgumentMatchers`. This class is now deprecated in order to
>   avoid a name clash with Hamcrest  * `org.hamcrest.Matchers`
>   class. This class will likely be removed in version 3.0.

I have written a little article on [mockito wildcards](https://www.sourceartists.com/blog/unit-testing/mockito-wildcards/3) if you're up for further reading.

Comment: How can I import org.mockito.ArgumentMatcher in Scala? I tried import org.mockito.ArgumentMatcher.any I get error `value any is not a member of object org.mockito.ArgumentMatcher

Comment: Could you please tell me what is the equivalent in version 3.0?

Comment: We shall know once it will be released ;)

Answer (score 13):

You can use `Mockito.isA()` for that:

```
import static org.mockito.Matchers.isA;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.verify;

verify(bar).doStuff(isA(Foo[].class));
```

http://site.mockito.org/mockito/docs/current/org/mockito/Matchers.html#isA(java.lang.Class)

Comment: This is the correct answer. Using any(Clazz) is completely wrong.

Comment: @SurasinTancharoen Actually, any(Class) is just an alias of isA(Class) (see the docs). So it's not at all wrong.

Comment: isA is deprecated

Answer (score 0):

In the recent version of Mockito you could use any(Foo.class)