# What does Mockito.anyLong() do?

Tags: java, junit, mockito

I have to test a method which takes a Long as argument. I have to test it for any value of the Long and also in case it's null. Does Mockito.anyLong() automatically test both cases? null and any value of the Long? Or randomly picks up a value between any long value and null?
Considering that these are the docs about anyLong():

> anyLong
>
> public static long anyLong()
>
> ```
> any long, Long or null.
>
> See examples in javadoc for Matchers class
>
> Returns:
>     0.
> ```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: it says, whatever input is(Long, long or null) - match this input. Saying so you don't care about actual value.

Comment: Note: Since Mockito 2.1.0, value should be any long or a non-null Long. So null is no longer a valid value!

Comment: related
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1778744/using-mockitos-generic-any-method

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's a matcher, not a test value generator. It's used for saying things like "I expect this stubbed method to be called with any long, Long or null but I don't care about the exact value".

Answer (score 3):

If you have `long` parameter and you manage to pass `null` as an argument to mock there will be NPE. If you have `Long` parameter `anyLong()` will allow `Long` and `null`, `long` will be autoboxed to `Long` by compiler. Try this

```
public class X  {
    long x(Long arg) {
        return 0;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        X x = mock(X.class);
        when(x.x(anyLong())).thenReturn(0L);
        System.out.println(x.x(null));
    }
}
```

it will print

```
0
0
```