# Can I use Mockito.any() into then method

Tags: spring, kotlin, mockito, springmockito, mockito-kotlin

I want to use any() inside then method. Here is my test code:

```
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension::class)
internal class UserSignInProviderTest {

    @Mock
    lateinit var authApiClient: AuthApiClient

    @Mock
    lateinit var userRepository: UserRepository

    @InjectMocks
    lateinit var userSignInProvider: UserSignInProvider


    @BeforeEach
    internal fun setUp() {
        userSignInProvider = UserSignInProvider(userRepository, authApiClient)
    }

    ...

}
```

There are 3 stubs here. In the first stub, you can use anyLong inside then.

```
@Test
fun refreshTokenTest() {
    // given.1
    whenever(authApiClient.validateRefreshToken(anyString())).then {
        println(">>> authApiClient.validateRefreshToken")
        return@then RefreshTokenValidateResponse(
            payload = RefreshTokenValidateResponse.Payload(anyLong())
        )
    }

   ...
}
```

However, it was not available for the second and third stubs. I want to know why it can't be used. Or I want to know how to use it.

```
    // given.2
    whenever(authApiClient.refreshToken(any())).then {
        println(">>> authApiClient.refreshToken")
        return@then ResponseEntity.ok().body(
            IssueTokenResponse(
                payload = IssueTokenResponse.Payload(
                    "any-string",
                    99,
                    "any-string"
                )
            )
        )
    }

    // given.3
    val user = User(
        id = 999,
        email = "any-string",
        name = "any-string"
    )

    whenever(userRepository.findById(anyLong())).then {
        Optional.of(user)
    }

    // when
    userSignInProvider.refreshToken(anyString())

    // then
    verify(authApiClient, times(1)).validateRefreshToken(anyString())
    verify(authApiClient, times(1)).refreshToken(any())
```

Of course, I tried the eq method instead of String("any-string"), but I got this error.

```
whenever(authApiClient.refreshToken(any())).then {
    println(">>> authApiClient.refreshToken")
    return@then ResponseEntity.ok().body(
        IssueTokenResponse(
            payload = IssueTokenResponse.Payload(eq("any-string"), anyLong(), eq("any-string"))
        )
    )
}

// Error
java.lang.NullPointerException: eq("any-string") must not be null
```

Comment: Please add the error that you get to the question, also clarify if you already took care of the null issues when using mockito in kotlin (https://github.com/mockito/mockito-kotlin/wiki, https://stackoverflow.com/a/48091649/9936828 , etc)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20899630/4571544

Answer (score 1):

Regarding your main question, why `any()` or `eq()` cannot be used

As mentioned in other answers, `any()` or `eq()` is returning null but your class expected a non-null value, therefore Kotlin throws an exception.

---

However, a more important concept to be clarified is the behaviour of `any()` or `eq()`.

They are not using to present any string or any value in the `then` block. So even you use them in `then` block they just a simple value. `any()` or `eq()` are for matching method parameters, they are expected to be used in

- `whenever()`: during the test if the mock is being called an, the mocking framework will do the matching for you, e.g.

```
whenever(authApiClient.validateRefreshToken(eq("abc"))).thenReturn(something())
// 
authApiClient.validateRefreshToken("abc") // returns something()
authApiClient.validateRefreshToken("qwe") // cannot return something()
```

- `verify(xxx).method(any())`: mocking framework records the interaction to the mock object within the test. This verify checks the interaction and then use the `any()` to verify does the interactions align with you matcher. e.g.

```
// during the test, below is called once
authApiClient.validateRefreshToken("any-string")

// in the test
verify(authApiClient, times(1)).validateRefreshToken(eq("abc")) // assertion fail
verify(authApiClient, times(1)).validateRefreshToken(eq("any-string")) // assertion success
verify(authApiClient, times(1)).validateRefreshToken(anyString()) // assertion success
```

To conclude, you don't need to return an instance with `any()` or `eq()` in the then block. Instead, you need put then in the `whenever` or `verify` to make the mocking framework behaves as what you expected.

Answer (score 0):

Mockito doesn't allow to mix raw values and matchers.

try with matchers :

```
// given.2
payload = IssueTokenResponse.Payload(eq("any-string"), anyLong(), eq("any-string"))
```

Comment: But I couldn't solve it. Even using eq, I get the following error: 
java.lang.NullPointerException: eq("any-string") must not be null

Comment: This can help understanding the NullPointerException https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59230041/argumentmatchers-any-must-not-be-null