# Why does hamcrest any(Myclass.class) requires casting

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito, hamcrest

I usually use Hamcrest like this:

```
doNothing().when(entityManagerMock).persist(any(Point.class));
```

then I have tried to write the same syntax on this:

```
doNothing().when(locationTagsMock).persistLocationTag(any(LocationTag.class));
```

But I got compilation error
which forced me to re-factor my code to this:

```
doNothing().when(locationTagsMock).persistLocationTag((LocationTag) any(LocationTag.class));
```

Why is the casting needed all the sudden?

How can I avoid it, if at all?

Comment: I think that this is a mockito question, not hamcrest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to Doppelganger's comment on the answer to [Using Mockito's generic "any()" method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1778744/using-mockitos-generic-any-method]), you've got a conflict between hamcrest's any() and mockito's any().

Comment: Either static import just the one intended (which I think is actually the mockito one), or import that class non-statically, or fully qualify the reference.