# How do I get Mockito to return data if parameter fields match but not necessarily the parameter object references themselves?

Tags: junit, mockito, junit4

I’m using Mockito 1.9.5, Maven 3.2.3, and JUnit 4.11.  I have the following set up in a JUnit test ...

```
    final Set<Account> accounts = new HashSet<Account>();
    final Account acct1 = new Account();
    acct1.setId(“id1”);
    accounts.add(acct1);
    …
    Mockito.doReturn(acctTeamMemberMap).when(m_accountTeamMemberDao).getManagers(accounts);
```

The problem is the Account objects I’m creating in my JUnit test are not the same objects that are actually being passed in as parameters when I execute the method call.  My question is, how do I tell Mockito to return the results when the ID fields of the various objects match the IDs I have in my JUnit test?  In other words, if the above Account objects have ids “id1” and “id2”, I would want Mockito to return the results always if the actual parameters also have ids “id1” and “id2”.

Thanks, - Dave

Answer (score 1):

You can use [any()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1778744/using-mockitos-generic-any-method) matcher from Mockito, and just return result no matter what value was passed:

```
Mockito.doReturn(acctTeamMemberMap).when(any()).getManagers(accounts);
```

Alternatively you can implement your own [matcher](http://mockito.googlecode.com/svn/branches/1.6/javadoc/org/mockito/ArgumentMatcher.html) and check if value that is was passed follows the specified constraints:

```
class IsListOfTwoElements extends ArgumentMatcher<List> {
      public boolean matches(Object myDao) {
          String id =  ((MyDao) myDao).size().getId();
          return id.equals("id1") || id.equals("id2");
      }
   }
```