# What do with() and any() methods?

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito

What does the following statement do :

```
  // The question is about the arguments being passed in the function.
 SomeReturnOutput = CallSomeFunction(with(any(Long.class)), with(any(List.class)));
```

I tried searching for it, but could not find a satisfying answer.
What does `with(any(Long.class))` and `with(any(List.class))` return ?

Comment: from which package do you import those functions?

Comment: Check "static import" directives at the top of your source file, they should tell you where `with` and `any` come from.

Comment: I'm still of the idea that's not a line of code... that's some pseudo code found in a book to explain some other concept....

Comment: @baao
I apologize,
I was confused.
It uses Java Mockito Library for writing unit tests.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The one "usage" of `any()` I know about - it is something that mocking libraries like Mockito make use of. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1778744/using-mockitos-generic-any-method) for example.

To be precise: when you have a mocked object and you specify "expected" calls, then you would be doing something like:

```
when(someMock.someMethod(any())).thenReturn(whatever);
```

This basically tells the framework: any object passed should "match". In contrast to:

```
when(someMock.someMethod(someSpecificValue)).thenReturn(whatever);
```

that means: only when someMethod() is invoked with that specific value, whatever should be returned.

`any(SomeClass.class)` is basically a "legacy" version - explicitly stating the expected class. See [here](https://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.2.7/org/mockito/ArgumentMatchers.html) for example for further documentation.

No idea about `with()` though.

Comment: Okay,
This seems correct. 
Now that I know its Mockito, I can go through the Documentation and check it out.
Thank you.

Comment: Just to be sure: I added another link to the corresponding documentation. But beyond that: when your code is **really** using with(any()) - then maybe this is not about mocking. But then you have to update the question and include the **import** statements at least.

Comment: `with()` may just be a no-op to make the code even more fluently readable I guess?

Comment: @QBrute Could be. But as said - I haven't seen that. And there is no with() method; neither in org.mockito.Mockito nor in the ArgumentsMatcher class.